# Method call on changing tabs in viewpager

Tags: android, tabs

How to call a method in a fragment when the tab is changed. 
I tried using onPause() in fragment, but it is not getting invoked.
I am using ViewPager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` method and use it for this purpose. `isVisibleToUser` will be `true` when the tab is changed and the fragment is selected and in other fragment which was previously visible, this method will be called with `false`.

**EDIT**:
`setUserVisibleHint` will be called multiple times. But in that case, you can rely on `getActivity()` not being null. i.e. `if (isVisibleToUser && getActivity() != null)`

Comment: But setUserVisibleHint() seems to get invoked before onViewCreated().
Is there any way to call it after onViewCreated()?

Comment: Trying. Thanks!

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to ViewPager by:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       <method call>
    }
}
```

So whenever user swipes through pages of ViewPager, you will get callback in onPageSelected() method with position of that page and there you can call fragment's method

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces here.
Define your interface in Activity that contains view pager

```
public interface MyInterface{
     void callMethod();
}
```

initialize interface and call like this

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

     }
     public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
     int positionOffsetPixels) {

     }

     public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       myInterface.callMethod();
    }
    });
```

And implement that method in your fragment and call your method in callback.

```
Myfragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface{
 //
  @Override
  void callMethod(){
     //call your method here
  }
```

}